# Using "Text to Columns" in a shared Excel 2010 worksheet

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, excel-2003, sharing, worksheet-function

I have a shared Excel worksheet (using .XLS due to compatibility issues), which I use with Excel 2010. One of the tasks in this worksheet is to enter a series of values from a Notepad file, which are tab/space separated. If I just do a copy from the notepad to the excel sheet, the "Text to Columns" is NOT ENABLED, and cannot be used.

Is there some other way to do this, without "un-sharing" Excel sheet? (which causes issues with the history and if the same is open with other users)

Comment: No answers, but the same question: http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/997401-text-columns-shared-workbook-office.html

Comment: MS Article on Excel 2010 unsupported features (does not mention "Text to Column"): http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-office-excel-2010-with-earlier-versions-of-excel-HA010342994.aspx?CTT=1#BM5a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find it on the limitations list, but I assume this is one of the features that is disabled on shared workbooks:

[Features that are unavailable in shared workbooks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/features-that-are-unavailable-in-shared-workbooks-HP005201080.aspx)

I'm afraid you'll need to un-share the workbook before being able to use the features listed.

Comment: The feature is disabled in the shared worksheet in Excel 2010. What I wanted to know - Is there a way to make something like that work when we have a shared workbook?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The only workaround I can think of (other than simply copying and pasting each value separately) is a macro that splits the text for you. This would introduce its own set of issues. First you have to write it, and second you cannot access or change the macro in shared mode.